# What does 嗦特嗦 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

Hello I'm wondering what would 嗦特嗦 mean? I've done a bit of research on baidu and I know 嗦 would mean eat/suck, 嗦嗦 is an onomatopoeia, 特 is special, but combined 嗦特嗦, it doesn't make much sense to me. Based on the context given, would this mean "eating snail noodle *sucking sound* (onomatopoeia)?"

Context: 不出任何意外，小助理苏小钰早早就蹲在马路边，捧着一碗螺蛳粉在大嗦特嗦。

Understanding: Not surprisingly, the little assistant 苏小钰 was squatting on the side of the road early, with a bowl of snail noodle in her hand and and eating a big bite (sucking noise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 大嗦特嗦

'嗦'/suo/ is the sound of sucking in something slippery, that's why it gained the meaning of ' to suck ; to slurp'

[大 + v + 特 + v] = [v in large scale + v in extraordinary way] = [earnestly + v]

**大嗦特嗦**螺蛳粉 = **earnestly sucking up** snail noodle

螺蛳粉 -- it is the noodle that's being sucked up, not the snail

[image: 螺蛳粉]

Other examples of the [大 + v + 特 + v] structure:

**大買特買** = **buy earnestly**

**大搶特搶** = **grab earnestly**

**大貪特貪** = commit corruption on a grand scale and in an extraordinary way = **commit corruption earnestly**

We use this structure for something we can "do on a grand scale and in an extraordinary way", or " do it earnestly/ seriously"

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so confusing!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to eat 螺蛳 (spiral shell) by sucking (嗦) the meat out of the shell. 大嗦特嗦 means the person is so enjoyed and working very hard on the delicious food. 大嗦 - give a hard suck; 特嗦 - give an even harder/extra hard suck.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: 吃螺該是用吮的, 嗦 is more like 'slurp'

Comment: I am not familiar with either word, but I think 嗦[suo] was used for its sound (similar to the noise from sucking). It can be a variation from "唆螺". After reading your answer, I don't find much difference though.

Comment: Whatever it is, there are two common Chinese ways to eat the snails, and that is to suck hard to get the snail out of its shell, or dig it out with a toothpick, unlike the French way where the snail meat is already "dug" out of its shell for cooking. So, contextually it is not all that unreasonable to interpret / translate 大嗦特嗦 as sucking hard on the snails.

Answer (score 1):

不出任何意外，
Not unexpectedly,
小助理苏小钰早早就蹲在马路边，
very early in the morning, little assistant Su, was squatting by the side of the road,
捧着一碗螺蛳粉在大嗦特嗦。
clasping a bowl of freshwater snail noodles （臭死）, suck-sucking them down the way only she can.